# How to create a line graph in jmeter based on my requirements?

Tags: jmeter

I require some guidance on a particular graph I want to create in jmeter. I might need to create a custom graph but if somebody can guide me on the steps to achieve the graph I require then it will be much appreciated.

I have three http request samplers in my jmeter test. Each sampler consists of a csv file but the difference between each sampler is the csv file is 100kb bigger.

So for example I might have the following results:

```
Label                                 Response time (ms)
Http sampler 100kb file              10000
Http sampler 200kb file              13000
HTTP sampler 300kb file              20000
```

I want to display a line graph with the following:

```
X axis - Label
Y axis - Response time
```

This would make a nice upward curve on the line graph.  I am not sure how to set this so if someone know then it's much appreciated. For some strange reason aggregate report listener doesn't show a graph but if I can display with different listener or jmeter plugin then I can do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [aggregate graph](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Graph)  over aggregate report?

> The aggregate graph is similar to the aggregate report. The primary difference is the aggregate graph provides an easy way to generate bar graphs and save the graph as a PNG file.

Comment: sorry I should say the aggregate graph as well on my jmeter does not display the graph. I'm not sure why it doesn't. It looked weird and buggy. If you don't my showing an example so I can see what the settings should be then I can try again?

Comment: @mmkp: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66492806/jmeter-aggregate-graph-not-showing-up-as-bar-chart Were you facing a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use 1 [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler for all 3 scenarios as if you go for different names - you will get 3 charts
2. Parameterize your CSV file using either [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) or [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter) so each virtual user (or loop) would use different CSV file
3. Resulting chart can be viewed via [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/) listener or the relevant graph of the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

   [image: JMeter Response Times Over Time]

Comment: hi I am walking to work now. Can you do me a favour and send me a screenshot of your sampler and CDC data configure so I know how to set it correctly for the 3 scenarios please?