# Jmeter Aggregate Graph not showing up as bar chart

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I have been trying to use Apache Jmeter for load testing. In the summary report, not able to see the bar chart. Attached the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

It is showing up as numbers as you can see. Am I missing anything?

Comment: You're missing second sampler

Comment: @DmitriT: Can you elaborate? Unable to understand. Do I need to tick/untick any option?

Comment: Show your test plan

Comment: @user7294900: what has the test plan to do with this? I was seeing the bar charts earlier but once I cleared everything and restarted the test, the bar chart stopped coming and started getting these numerical values on the graph.

Comment: results depends also on listener scope, if other samplers in different scope they won't shown in graph

Comment: looks like a bug @user7294900 After restarting jmeter after several days, I could see the graph. After clearing the results and then load testing again, now I cannot see the bar chart. Looks like a macOS bug. So using jp@gc - Response time percentiles as a listener now

Answer (score 0):

Check your jdk version.
You should use JDK8, not JDK11 or 17,